# Obtain full application information from running task info

Tags: android

I have the following piece of code

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);

ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo activityname = taskInfo.get(0);
```

And what I'd like to do is obtain **as most information** as it is available about that certain app (like title, version, description, function, permissions, google store key, package name, (...) but I don't understand `activityname.describeContents()` because it returns an `int` and I can't manage to print it and `toString()` hands out pratically nothing. Can someone give me some help please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `RunningTaskInfo`, you want to look at the `baseActivity` value.

From the `baseActivity.getPackageName()`, you have the package name you were after.  Once you have that, you can use the `PackageManager` to give you access to all the other pieces of information you seek.

Comment: I'm not fully understading what I should get and which methods to implement, can you give me an easy example following the ComponentInfo from `baseActivity` ?